# How to add my Python program in cloud and run it in Android app

Tags: python, function, cloud

I programmed a Python program that can take a photo as an input and find faces (Face Detection). But I want to implement it in a cloud server.

My program should go and read the python code from the server and return a valuel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your python program and make it an endpoint on a flask or django server.

Or if you don't want to host your server, put your program into for example an AWS Lambda and make it access it with API Gateway (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html)